# «И пр.», «и др.», «и т. п.», «и т. д.» в падежной форме

Tags: грамотная-речь, сокращения, условные-сокращения

«И пр.», «и др.», «и т. д.», «и т. п.» являются сокращениями "и прочее/прочий/прочая/прочие", "и другое/другой/другая/другие", "и так далее", "и тому подобное". Сокращения подразумевают именительный падеж вышеупомянутых слов и сочетаний.

Вопрос: можно ли эти сокращения употреблять там, где подразумевается другая падежная форма?

1. *Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и пр. [в прочем]*.
2. *Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и др. [в другом]*.
3. *Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и т. д. [**и в так далее?**]*.
4. *Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и т. п. [и в тому подобном]*.

Comment: "И **в** так далее" точно звучит очень странно. :)

Comment: И в так далее, и в тому подобном  — так вообще ни говорят.

Comment: @Серж не наговаривайте. "В тому плодобном" - вполне корректная грамматическая конструкция, другое дело, что она здесь просто неуместна по контексту, - ни вообще, ни тем более в виде предлагаемого сокращения.

Comment: "И т. п." и подобные можно считать неизменяемыми формами". Это не вы писали? Вы сами себе противоречите.

Comment: @Серж да это писал. А про "сам себе противоречите" - писал не я. Вам и комментировать.))) Могу только извиниться за случайную описку в слове "плодобном".

Answer (score 1):

> Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и пр. (в прочем).
>   Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и др. (в другом).
>   Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и т. д. (и в так далее?).
>   Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и т. п. (и в тому подобном).

Почему перед скобками стоит: и пр., и др., и т. д., и т. п., а в скобках все эти же, но с предлогом "в"? Думаете, воспринимающий человек поймёт, что надо читать, как в скобках? Не поймёт, он читает, как в самом предложении: прочее, другое, так далее, и тому подобное. Если бы поставили предлог "в" перед перечисленными сокращениями, то тогда другое дело (но обычно перед такими сокращениями предлог не ставится - непонятно будет).

Comment: Всё, что в скобках, — это примечание. Я просто указал падёжную форму того слова/сочетания, которое сокращается.

Comment: Я заменил круглые скобки на квадратные. Так, наверное, будет правильнее.

Comment: не будет человек читать так же, как в скобках, ведь до скобок сокращение без предлога

Comment: В скобках примечание для нас — участников сообщества, а не для читателя.

Comment: я понял, не читают так, как не в тексте

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что в художественном тексте даже подобные сокращения нежелательны.
В юридически обязывающих текстах подобное вообще недопустимо.
Научный же и отчасти деловой стиль предполагают (хотя это тоже в явном виде нигде не написано явно) лишь некоторые из общеупотребительных сокращений. "И пр." в них не входит, принятая форма - "и проч.". "И др.", насколько помню, используется главным образом в значении "и другие" - то есть в отношении персон.

Теперь собственно ответ.
Никаких "косвенных падежей" в ваших примерах нет. "И т. п."  и подобные можно считать неизменяемыми формами. И дело тут не в сокращениях. ***Исходные выражения "И прочее", "И так далее" и "И тому подобное" используются для любого падежа и не допускают перед собой никаких предлогов.***  Ваши попытки пристроить предлог к "так далее" просто не находят соответствия ни в одном письменном тексте.

Если же смотреть на грамматику (и закрыть глаза на саму неупотребительность подобных конструкций в примерах подобных вашим), то предложения звучать будут так.

*Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке **и прочие**.

Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке **и другие**.

Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке **и так далее**.

Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке **и тому подобные**.*

На мой взгляд, первые две конструкции в данном контексте вообще не требуют и не допускают сокращений, а две другие теоретически могут быть сокращены до обычных "и т. д." и "и т. п." - но только в частной переписке.

Comment: В вашем варианте смысл меняется: сочетания "и прочие", "и другие", "и так далее", "и тому подобные" относятся уже к ошибкам, а не к аспектам текста, в которых они допущены.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко *В вашем варианте смысл меняется* - Господь с Вами, по сравнению с чем он меняется?!  *сочетания "и прочие", "и другие", "и так далее", "и тому подобные" относятся уже к ошибкам* -  не понял. Они не относятся к ошибкам. Это единственно правильный литературный вариант "расшифровки" сокрашений. Вы, простите, что-то тут замудрили... А кто вам сказал, что это ошибки?!

Comment: Ваш вариант: "Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и прочие [ошибки]". Мой вариант: "Я указал ваши ошибки — в оформлении, вёрстке и пр. [в прочем, в прочих аспектах текста]".

Comment: Ваш вариант некорректен. Если вы настаиваете на подобном прочтении, пишите полностью. Тогда и вопросом про падеж не будет. Впрочем, вы так и не ответили, в чем изменился смысл.

Comment: Я указал в прошлом комментарии в квадратных скобках: в вашем варианте  "и прочие" относится к ошибкам, а у меня "и пр." относится к аспектам текста, в которых допускаются ошибки, наподобие оформления и вёрстки.

Comment: Я уж не говорю о том, что слово термин "аспект" здесь вообще выглядит некорректным.

Comment: <...> и прочие, и другие... что? Ваше сокращения вообще не связаны с текстом. Непонятно к чему они относятся.

Comment: @Серж Даже автор вопроса понял, "к чему относятся", хотя и не согласился принять испавлкение. Относятся они к слову "ошибки" - как это и следует из логики и синтаксиса.

Comment: В моём варианте — при отнесении сокращений «и пр.», «и др.», «и т. д.», «и т. п.» к аспектам текста, а не к ошибкам — возможно ли употребление этих сокращений, то есть когда дополняемые существительные стоят в косвенном падеже?